# JDBC Type 3 Driver

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

Today I was learning different JDBC drivers. I found in below site

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2000/jw-0707-jdbc.html?page=4

that JDBC-ODBC Bridge takes more time than the other drivers including Type - 3. But when I was looking at the Type - 3 dirver

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2002/jw-0517-jdbcdriver.html?page=2

where it is said that it uses middle-tier to communicate to server. Middle-tier uses JDBC-ODBC bridge to talk to the server. If this is the architecture then how come Type - 3 takes less time  when compared to Type - 1 since Type - 3 itself uses Type -1 . Please clarify me and correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: The first article is from more than twelve years ago and is using `JDK 1.2.1` (!!) and other obsolete technologies. If you want to learn about `JDBC` there are definitely better sources out there.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the driver doesn't inherently influence its performance.  How well the driver is written could make a dramatic difference, and quite often the performance of the actual database will override any performance influence from the the driver itself.  not to mention that for a given database setup, you may only be able to use certain driver types (or be able to find certain implementation types).  long story short, those articles tell you nothing.  test the drivers you have available with the types of workloads you require and determine for yourself which driver makes the most sense.

as the one comment mentioned, those articles are *ancient* in computer terms.  on top of that, the second article refers to a specific jdbc implementation (that of the article) which uses the JDBC-ODBC bridge in its implementation.  as such, the timing in the first article is completely unrelated to the implementation from the second article.

I will point out, however, that the JDBC-ODBC bridge tends to be the shakiest performer when compared to any "real" jdbc driver implementations (ones designed for a specific database vendor).

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any good reason why someone would use anything other than a type IV JDBC driver from their database vendor of choice.  All the ones worth using have drivers: MySQL, Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server.

Very few Java articles from 2000 are still worth citing.

Comment: At least as-of a few years ago, there were features in the Oracle Type 2 (OCI) driver that weren't in the type 4 driver. TNS Naming was one of them, but I recall a couple of others.

Comment: I'm sure there are features that are different.  I'm questioning whether they're still worth pursuing.